# How get location inside a controller with module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After put my controller inside a module:

```
module Admin
  class CampaignsController < AdminController # :nodoc:
    ...

    def create
      @campaign = Campaign.new create_params

      if @campaign.save
        render json: @campaign, status: :created, location: @campaign
      else
        render json: { errors: @campaign.errors.full_messages },
               status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

The location not works more:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `campaign_url' for #<Admin::CampaignsController:0x007fbf36353f48>>
```

Only works if I hard coded it `location: admin_campaign_url(@campaign)`.

Have a smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `campaign_url` helper method is controlled by the routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :campaigns
end
```

Will create the `campaign_url` and it will call `Admin::CampaignsController` but, also, the URL will be `/campaigns`, without `/admin`.

You can also try:

```
scope '/admin', module: 'admin' do
  resources :campaigns
end
```

Where you will have a `campaigns_url` helper method, which will call to `Admin::CampaignsController` controller and the URL will be `/admin/campaigns`.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I have public campaigns using `/campaigns`.

Comment: You can pass `module:` directly to `resources` like this: `resources :campaigns, module: 'admin'`.